# Use salt as identifier for crypted session id in database based authentication system for webapp

Tags: authentication, salt, session-management

I have written a database-based authentication framework for webapps I am planning to program in the future.

The framework is implemented by using the plpgsql-language of a PostgreSQL-Database and therefore the extension pgcrypto is used to encrypt sensitive information.

If the user of a webapp authenticates (so the webserver fires up sth.) like

```
select authenticate('user@email.com', 'login-token')
```

the database returns

```
False, Invalid user / login token
```

or

```
True, Successfully logged in, session-id
```

The session-id is transmitted to the webserver in cleartext, so a cookie can be created, while it is saved in the database by applying a hashing algorithm, which comes with the pgcrypto-extension. This is a kind of bcrypt-implementation (the PostgreSQL-Documentation is kind of vague). The session-id is combined with an unique salt (one per session-id).

So in the session-table you find sth. like

```
|primary key|user-id|bcrypt(session-id)|other information
```

The question is about the function which is used to check if the session-id is valid and which user it is about. This function is fired, when the user presents a session-id to the webserver, who is in turn to validate this session-id.

```
select get_user_by_session_id(session-id)
```

If there is no additional identifier the select-part has the following problem:

**For each row in the session-table the hash-function must be applied to the given session-id.**

This works like

- select a row of session-table
- read the salt and hash the user-given session-id
- compare the result with the hash of the actual row
- repeat until found a match (return True) or the end of table is reached without any match (return False)

**This is kind of slow (slower if more sessions are there).**

So the idea is to use an identifier, which is unsensitive to do the following (pseudocode)

- select get_user_by_session_id(user-given-dentifier, session_id)
- select hash from session-table where identifier=user-given-identifier
- check if hash_function(session_id) = hash

This has the advantage, that only one crypto-operation is necessary, instead of one for each row in the session table until the valid one is found.

In the current design there are two possible identifiers I could give to the user.

- A static unique member_key which is generated at the registration for each user.
- The salt used for encrypt / hash the session-id

I would go for the salt, because I wanted to use the member_key for identification purposes (support calls) or something else.
I don't see any problems with this, because of the following reasons:

- in general the salt must not be encrypted and can be saved in plain text
- only the webserver and the user himself sees the salt (webserver during transmit, user in the cookie)
- the attacker only can get this salt by intercepting the connection - if he does this, he also get the session-id in plaintext

Do I miss anything? Does the static member_key have any advantages over the salt?

Comment: I'm having trouble following what you are doing. You mention using a hash function on lookup but don't actually say where you are using a hash funciton. The only algorithm you mention is Blowfish which is an encryption algorithm. And why are you salting the session IDs at all?

Comment: @NeilSmithline I added some information. The used hash algorithm is based on the blowfish cipher and should be bcrypt. The postgresql-wiki is kind of vague about the explicit implementation.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this method?

Comment: I don't want to save the session-id unencrypted in the database. As the session-id is a sensitive information I just save a hash of it in the database. So potential data theft or a "lost" backup doesn't enable the attacker to get in touch with a valid (possible due to persistent validity or long expiration dates) session-id to impersonate the user.
This attack vector is probably theoretical (because the cookie which is presented to the webserver is also signed, so that the attacker must still break this), but I don't see an disadvantage against this "defense-in-depth"-idea. Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the primary-key of the Users-Table with an uuid instead of a big serial and used this as insensitive information.

The session-id at the client looks like ||.

With this I could minimized the session-lookup from > 1 sec to about 100ms.